# How can I remove all commands in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to remove every commands in macOS with help of `.commandsRemoved()` which is doing good job, but I can see there is some that did not get removed like **ShowTabBar** or **ShowAllTabs**:

```
@main
struct testApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commandsRemoved()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove the app title menu on the bar, but the following will work to remove all of the commands under it. First, add the following line of code to your App `struct`:

```swift
@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

Then, create a new file called AppDelegate (or whatever you will remember - this can also be in the same file). Create an `AppDelegate`:

```swift
//In the file, you must import `AppKit`

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
            NSWindow.allowsAutomaticWindowTabbing = false //<-- This is the key!

            //This will hide all of the fullscreen and tab menu controls
        
    }
}
```

This code was tested with Xcode 14 and macOS 13.

### References

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/what-s-the-swiftui-way-to-do-this-appdelegate-thing/10559

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65634944/20384561

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1646657-allowsautomaticwindowtabbing